# Problems calculating stride and offset in WritePixels

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am writing a Kinect application, where I use the color image from the sensor. I get a 640 x 480 color image, I copy the data from the sensor to a WriteableBitmap, with the WritePixels method. When I use the whole color image I have no issues. But I would like to use only the middle part of the image. But I can't get stride and or offset right?

To copy the whole image I do the following:

```
_colorImageWritableBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorImageFrame.Width, colorImageFrame.Height),
                _colorImageData,
                colorImageFrame.Width * Bgr32BytesPerPixel,
                0);
```

As I mention I only want the middle part of the image. I would like to start at a width at 185px and take the next 270px, and stop there. And I use the the whole height.

My PixelFormat is bgr32, so to calculate the byte pr. pixel I use:

```
var bytesPrPixel = (PixelFormats.Bgr32.BitsPerPixel + 7)/8;
```

And my stride:

```
var stride = bytesPrPixel*width;
```

The writepixel method:

```
_colorImageWritableBitmap.WritePixels(
                new Int32Rect(0, 0, colorImageFrame.Width, colorImageFrame.Height),
                _colorImageData, stride, offset);
```

But when I change the width to other than 640, the image gets wrong (hidden in noise).

Can someone help me, to understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you want center square or circle?

Comment: Just use the center rectangle 270 x 480

Comment: Do you edit the width while running? if so you would need to edit the stride and every other var using width too.

Comment: No my width is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to properly copy the pixels from the source bitmap. Assuming that the source `colorImageFrame` is also a BitmapSource, you would do it this way:

```
var width = 270;
var height = 480;
var x = (colorImageFrame.PixelWidth - width) / 2;
var y = 0;
var stride = (width * colorImageFrame.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
var pixels = new byte[height * stride];
colorImageFrame.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, width, height), pixels, stride, 0);
```

Now you could write the pixel buffer to your WriteableBitmap by:

```
colorImageWritableBitmap.WritePixels(
    new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), pixels, stride, 0);
```

Or instead of using WriteableBitmap, you just create a new BitmapSource, like:

```
var targetBitmap = BitmapSource.Create(
    width, height, 96, 96, colorImageFrame.Format, null, pixels, stride);
```

However, the easiest way to create a crop of the source bitmap might be to used a `CroppedBitmap` like this:

```
var targetBitmap = new CroppedBitmap(
    colorImageFrame, new Int32Rect(x, y, width, height));
```

Comment: Thank you Clemns, I had to work on the implementation, so haven't been able to come with a constructive comments before now. I solved my problem using the CroppedBitmap method. Thanks again :)