# Clip region not working

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, crop

My WPF application has a custom control I wrote specifically for displaying part of a bitmap.  The bitmap is contained in an object transmitted to my program from my company's back end Windows service as a `byte` array.  Included in the data is a rectangle which specifies the part of the image of interest which needs to be displayed.

Further, when the user clicks on the control, it cycles between three different "magnifications" of that region.  This setting is called the "zoom state".  Essentially, at one setting, the rectangle that is displayed is larger in width by 60 pixels than the region specified by the rectangle transmitted with the data.  At the second setting, the rectangle's width is increased by 25%, and at the third, it is increased by 50%.  The height is always computed to keep the aspect ratio of the portion of the bitmap displayed the same as the control's.

To date, I've been generating new bitmaps from the data that are cropped to the region specified by the rectangle computations described above.  However, given the amount of data that we receive, and the size of the bitmaps, this is using huge amounts of memory.  I need to find a way to reduce the memory consumption.

I did a search on cropping images in WPF & found [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms746710%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on clipping an image.  This seemed ideal, as I'm already computing a rectangle and it seems this would use a lot less memory.  So I modified my code this morning so that instead of creating a `CroppedBitmap` from the original image & an `Int32Rect`, it creates a `RetangleGeometry` struct and sets the `Image` control's `Clip` property to that rectangle.  The result, however, is I'm not seeing anything at all.

I commented out the code that creates the `RectangleGeometry` and I do see the whole image in the control at that point, so I know that the problem is somewhere in the code that computes the rectangle.  I know the computations in the code are right, but I must be missing something when I convert it into a `RectangleGeometry`.

Here's the template that the custom control uses:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ZoomableImage}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ZoomableImage}">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                        ContextMenu="{TemplateBinding ContextMenu}"
                        Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                        Name="ImageBorder">
                    <Image BitmapEffect="{TemplateBinding BitmapEffect}" 
                           BitmapEffectInput="{TemplateBinding BitmapEffectInput}"
                           CacheMode="{TemplateBinding CacheMode}"
                           Effect="{TemplateBinding Effect}" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                           Name="Image" 
                           Source="{TemplateBinding ImageToBeZoomed}"
                           Stretch="{TemplateBinding Stretch}" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And here's the code that computes the clip rectangle:

```
private void CreateClipRectangle() {
    Rect srcRect = new Rect( PlateRectangle.X, PlateRectangle.Y, PlateRectangle.Width, PlateRectangle.Height );

    // We want to show some pixels outside the plate's rectangle, so add 60 to the PlateRectangle's Width.
    srcRect.Width += 60.0;

    // Adjust the Width property for the ZoomState, which increases the height & width of the rectangle around the license plate
    if ( ZoomState == ZoomStates.ZoomPlus25 ) {
        srcRect.Width = srcRect.Width * 1.25;
    } else if ( ZoomState == ZoomStates.ZoomPlus50 ) {
        srcRect.Width = srcRect.Width * 1.50;
    }

    // Make sure that srcRect.Width is not bigger than the ImageToBeZoomed's PixelWidth!
    if ( srcRect.Width > ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth ) srcRect.Width = ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth;

    // We need to keep the aspect ratio of the source rectangle the same as the Image's.
    // Compute srcRect.Height so the srcRect will have the correct aspect ratio, but don't let 
    // the rectangle's height get bigger than the original image's height!
    srcRect.Height = Math.Min( ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight, Math.Round( srcRect.Width * ImageBorder.ActualHeight / ImageBorder.ActualWidth ) );

    // Adjust srcRect.X & srcRect.Y to center the source image in the output image
    srcRect.X = srcRect.X - ( srcRect.Width  - PlateRectangle.Width  ) / 2.0;
    srcRect.Y = srcRect.Y - ( srcRect.Height - PlateRectangle.Height ) / 2.0;

    // Adjust srcRect to keep the cropped region from going off the image's edges.
    if ( srcRect.X < 0 ) srcRect.X = 0.0;
    if ( srcRect.Y < 0 ) srcRect.Y = 0.0;
    if ( ( srcRect.X + srcRect.Width  ) > ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth  ) srcRect.X = ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth  - srcRect.Width;
    if ( ( srcRect.Y + srcRect.Height ) > ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight ) srcRect.Y = ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight - srcRect.Height;

    // Create a new RectangleGeometry object that we will use to clip the ImageToBeZoomed and put it into the Clip property.
    ImageControl.Clip = new RectangleGeometry( srcRect, 0.0, 0.0 );
}
```

`ImageToBeZoomed` is a `DependencyProperty` that is of type `BitmapSource`.  The `byte` array is converted into a `BitmapImage` using this code:

```
public static BitmapImage BitmapFromBytes( byte[] imageBytes ) {
        BitmapImage image  = null;
        if ( imageBytes != null ) {
            image = new BitmapImage();
            try {
                using ( MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream( imageBytes ) ) {
                    image.BeginInit();
                    image.CacheOption  = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    image.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                    image.EndInit();

                    // Freeze the BitmapImage.  This helps plug memory leaks & saves memory.
                    image.Freeze();
                }
            } catch ( Exception ex ) {
                // . . .
            }
        }
        return image;
    }
```

The values in the `PlateRectangle` property are `ints` and they are in pixels.  Could the problem have something to do with needing to convert from pixels to device independent units?

**EDIT 1**

In playing with this, I've found that I see no image if I set the Y coordinate of the `RectangleGeometry` struct's `Rect` property to anything other than 0 or negative values.  This makes no sense to me.  In most cases, the area of concern is in the middle of the image & no where near the top or bottom edge.  Does anyone have any ideas why this is so?

**Edit 2**

Am I the only one who is having problems with the WPF `Clip` functionality?

Comment: Did you consider to simply create a copy of the pixel buffer, as e.g. shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23810646/1136211)?

Comment: That's exactly what I was doing and that's inefficient.  I'm trying to reduce the program's memory usage.

Comment: is it possible for you to post a working sample of your code with sample image data? I do have some exp in graphics, may I have something for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Rect` you're using for `RectangleGeometry` is not being scaled. There also seem to be a few other scaling issues in there.

I replaced your `CreateClipRectangle` method with this (see inline comments for what was changed/added):

```
   private void CreateClipRectangle()
    {
        Rect srcRect = new Rect(PlateRectangle.X, PlateRectangle.Y, PlateRectangle.Width, PlateRectangle.Height);

        // We want to show some pixels outside the plate's rectangle, so add 60 to the PlateRectangle's Width.
        srcRect.Width += 60.0;

        // Adjust the Width property for the ZoomState, which increases the height & width of the rectangle around the license plate
        if (ZoomState == ZoomStates.ZoomPlus25)
        {
            srcRect.Width = srcRect.Width * 1.25;
        }
        else if (ZoomState == ZoomStates.ZoomPlus50)
        {
            srcRect.Width = srcRect.Width * 1.50;
        }

        // Make sure that srcRect.Width is not bigger than the ImageToBeZoomed's PixelWidth!
        if (srcRect.Width > ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth) srcRect.Width = ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth;

        // We need to keep the aspect ratio of the source rectangle the same as the Image's.
        // Compute srcRect.Height so the srcRect will have the correct aspect ratio, but don't let 
        // the rectangle's height get bigger than the original image's height!
        double aspectRatio = ((double)ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight / ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth); // <-- ADDED
        srcRect.Height = Math.Min(ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight, Math.Round(srcRect.Width * aspectRatio)); // <-- CHANGED

        // Adjust srcRect.X & srcRect.Y to center the source image in the output image
        srcRect.X = srcRect.X - srcRect.Width / 2.0; // <-- CHANGED
        srcRect.Y = srcRect.Y - srcRect.Height / 2.0; // <-- CHANGED

        // Adjust srcRect to keep the cropped region from going off the image's edges.
        if (srcRect.X < 0) srcRect.X = 0.0;
        if (srcRect.Y < 0) srcRect.Y = 0.0;
        if ((srcRect.X + srcRect.Width) > ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth) srcRect.X = ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth - srcRect.Width;
        if ((srcRect.Y + srcRect.Height) > ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight) srcRect.Y = ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight - srcRect.Height;

        double scaleX = (ImageControl.ActualWidth / ImageToBeZoomed.PixelWidth); // <-- ADDED
        double scaleY = (ImageControl.ActualHeight / ImageToBeZoomed.PixelHeight); // <-- ADDED

        srcRect.X *= scaleX; // <-- ADDED
        srcRect.Y *= scaleY; // <-- ADDED
        srcRect.Width *= scaleX; // <-- ADDED
        srcRect.Height *= scaleY; // <-- ADDED

        // Create a new RectangleGeometry object that we will use to clip the ImageToBeZoomed and put it into the Clip property.
        ImageControl.Clip = new RectangleGeometry(srcRect, 0.0, 0.0);
    }
```

My ImageControl XAML was just

```
<Image Name="ImageControl" Stretch="Uniform" />
```

There may be further issues with the bounds checking, and I removed the border stuff that I wasn't sure about but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: Thank you!  This makes sense.  I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: This isn't working. I think it might have something to do with the fact that the `PlateRectangle` is only a very small part of the image and I'm trying to display only the pixels in that area in a portion of the display that's smaller than the overall image.  I have a feeling that using a `CroppedBitmap`to display that area is the only way to work.  What I think is happening is that since the area on the screen is smaller than the whole image, the part of the image that would be shown is not included in the region that would be displayed in the control.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily using smaller images or a larger region? You may want to move the part into an isolated project just to be sure what's happening. I can provide the project that was working for me if you want it.

Comment: If it worked for you, then I'm going to give you the bounty.  What you did worked; the fact it doesn't work for me must mean it's the data that's tripping me up.

Comment: Even if I set the region to 10 pixels square and shrink the window very small I can still see something. Your comment about only being able to see the image at Y <= 0 is especially strange. Wish I could help further.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are using HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
and VerticalAlignment="Stretch" which is throwing off the co-ordinate system of the displayed image.

try something like

```
<Image Source="...." HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="None"/>
```